# What is the safest way to pass a unique_ptr through a function requiring a void* param?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I am creating a thread under Windows which requires a parameter block to be passed as a void* (LPVOID).

The calling function heap-allocates the parameter block, since the spawned thread may outlive the calling function.  The calling function does not need to share ownership of the parameter block.

Here is my thinking so far:

```
...
using Functor = std::function<void()>

class SpawnData
{
public:
    SpawnData(Functor func) : func(func) {}
    Functor func;
};

DWORD WINAPI MyTaskLauncher(LPVOID ppRawData)
{
    assert(ppRawData != nullptr);
    //auto pData = *static_cast<std::unique_ptr<SpawnData>*>(ppRawData); //not permitted (A)
    auto ppData = static_cast<std::unique_ptr<SpawnData>*>(ppRawData); //Feels safe, but...
    assert(*ppRawData != nullptr);
    (*ppRawData)->func();  //could dereference invalid memory?
}

ThreadId MyThreadSpawner(Functor func)
{
    auto pData = std::make_unique<SpawnData>(func);

    //CreateThread() is Windows API with a void* signature for the data param
    ... = CreateThread(..., static_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(MyTaskLauncher),
                      static_cast<LPVOID>(&(pData.get())), ...); //Ugh... :(

    threadId = ...;
    return threadId;
}
```

My questions:

1) Would you agree that there is a race condition starting at the call to CreateThread() for MyTaskLauncher to re-wrap the raw pointer before MyThreadSpawner() exits?

2) Would you agree that Q1) is essentially moot because MyThreadSpawner()'s pData will be destroyed when it goes out of scope *regardless* of whether MyTaskLauncher had already "wrapped" its memory or not?

3) What's the safest way to strip, pass and re-wrap on the other side my smart pointer through the CreateThread() API?

Consider the following:

```
DWORD WINAPI MyTaskLauncher(LPVOID pRawData)
{
    assert(pRawData != null)
    auto pData = std::make_unique<SpawnData>(*static_cast<SpawnData*>(pRawData));
    //signal MyThreadSpawner() that SpawnData is safely wrapped
    //...do work...
    return result;
}

ThreadId MyThreadSpawner(Functor func)
{
    auto pData = std::make_unique<SpawnData>(func);

    //CreateThread() is Windows API with a void* signature for the data param
    ... = CreateThread(..., static_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(MyTaskLauncher),
                      static_cast<LPVOID>(pData.get()), ...); //Hmm...        

    threadId = ...;
    //Wait for MyTaskLauncher to signal SpawnData is safely wrapped
    return threadId;
}
```

4) Is this legal?  For a time, there will be two, er, unique_ptrs pointing to the very same memory...

If I update this to use shared_ptr as follows:

```
//MyTaskLauncher:
    ...
    auto pData = *static_cast<std::shared_ptr<SpawnData>*>(pRawData));  // (B)
    ...

//MyThreadSpawner:
    auto pData = std::make_shared<SpawnData>(func);
    ...
```

5) The line marked (B), above is legal, whereas (A) far above (which does the same to a `std::unique_ptr<SpawnData>*`), is not.  Can anyone shed some light on as to why?

6) And finally, any suggestions on simpler and/or safer techniques for passing safe data through a function signature requiring a void*?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: There is no "safe" way to do this, once you cast to `void*` the type system is off and`&pData` is an address in the stack.

Comment: It seems to me like the caller shouldn't use a `unique_ptr` at all. The new thread might use a `unique_ptr`, but I think the caller would be better off with a raw pointer.

Comment: @user That is probably the pragmatic answer, I grant you, but as the solution ages and is maintained, I would sleep better knowing that the heap allocations are protected to the maximum degree possible.  Also I feel that a hurdle like a non-typesafe API dependency should explicitly not have the ripple effect of causing the abandonment of best-practices elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @imreal patched the &pData issue--thank you.  Re: not possible: Looking at the shared_ptr solution I've shown, I believe it is a solution, as it does appear to guarantee that SpawnData cannot be leaked, does it not?  Am I missing something?  Assuming yes, I am seeking advice/feedback on whether there are better techniques.

Comment: It looks to me like you are passing the address of a raw pointer and casting it to a `std::unique_ptr*`. I would just pass the raw pointer if the thread will outlive the `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @bRadGibson I would pass a raw pointer and handle ownership in a singleton

Comment: Downvoting?  If you have enough rep to do it, you should know the drill: leave a comment why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2) Would you agree that Q1) is essentially moot because MyThreadSpawner()'s pData will be destroyed when it goes out of scope regardless of whether MyTaskLauncher had already "wrapped" its memory or not?

Yes. That's what a `unique_ptr` is; it represents *unique* ownership. You're trying to break that.

> 3) What's the safest way to strip, pass and re-wrap on the other side my smart pointer through the CreateThread() API?

Define "safest". It's not clear why `MyThreadSpawner` is using a `unique_ptr` at all.

You are trying to transfer ownership of a `unique_ptr`. So you need to actually do that; the sender must lose ownership and the receiver must acquire it. That's pretty trivial:

```
DWORD WINAPI MyTaskLauncher(LPVOID pData)
{
    assert(pData!= nullptr);
    //Gain ownership of memory.
    unique_ptr<SpawnData> pSpawnData(static_cast<SpawnData*>(pData));
    pSpawnData->func();
}

ThreadId MyThreadSpawner(Functor func)
{
    auto pData = std::make_unique<SpawnData>(func);

    //CreateThread() is Windows API with a void* signature for the data param
    ... = CreateThread(..., static_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(MyTaskLauncher),
                      //Lose ownership of memory.
                      static_cast<LPVOID>(pData.release()), ...);     
    threadId = ...;
    return threadId;
}
```

> 5) The line marked (B), above is legal, whereas (A) far above (which does the same to a std::unique_ptr*), is not. Can anyone shed some light on as to why?

Legal in what sense? The void* does not point to a `shared_ptr` of any sort. Therefore casting it to a `shared_ptr` and then accessing it is not legal C++.

Just because your compiler just so happened to let you do it doesn't make it legal.

> And finally, any suggestions on simpler and/or safer techniques for passing safe data through a function signature requiring a void*?

Yes: use `std::thread`. You can get a Win32 thread handle via [`thread::native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle).

Comment: The intent behind MyThreadSpawner() using a unique_ptr is the usual: to ensure that a resource it allocated is safely disposed of upon departure of scope (eg. exception) up until the moment ownership is handed off or the object is no longer needed. Thank you--your answer is very helpful.